# Modelagem para frequência de alunos

Tags: mysql, sql, modelagem

Tenho dúvida em relação a estrutura do banco de dados para um sistema de frequência. Pensei em duas estruturas e ao fazer um busca vi que as duas existem e são usadas em sistemas distintos.
1 -  A primeira eu tenho uma tabela `frequencia` onde tenho as colunas `id_aluno` e `id_reuniao`.
Nesta estrutura guardo apenas os membros presentes, sendo que não presentes não serão gravados.

2 -  A segunda eu tenho uma tabela `frequencia` onde tenho as colunas `id_aluno`, `id_reuniao` e `type`.
Nesta estrutura guardo tantos presentes quanto ausentes, e isso definido pelo campo `tipo` onde `0 = ausente` e `1 = presente`.

Num relatório futuro irei listar todos os membros e marcar os dias em que os mesmo estiveram presentes. Esse relatório será para as duas estruturas.

Terá o seguinte modelo:

```
Membro           Dia    Dia    Dia   Dia
                 5      8      12    30    
1 - João         P      A      A     P
1 - Maria        P      P      P     P
```

As colunas dias são os dias de reunião num relatório onde escolho `data inicial` e `data final` Portanto ele não segue um padrão. Poderá ter mês com apenas uma reunião ou inúmeras.
Irei fazer um `select` para listar todos os membros e pra cada membro um `select` dos dias de reunião do intervalo.

Assumindo a primeira estrutura faço teste se o aluno existe no dia da reunião. Se sim marco como presente se não marco como Ausente.

Assumindo a segunda estrutura farei um `select` de todos os membro e em cada membro um `select` testando o campo `tipo`.

Minha dúvida é: Qual das seguintes estruturas terei mais agilidade e facilidade para gerar relatórios? Ou se possuem alguma estrutura mais adequada para esse tipo de sistema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o mais recomendado seria optar pela primeira opção criar uma tabela de `presenca`, na qual você grava apenas os presentes em cada reunião, relacionando `id_aluno` e `id_reuniao`.

Na hora de gerar o relatório você sabe que quem não tem registro de presença estava ausente.

Dessa forma você economiza memória por ter menos registros, e também por ter uma coluna a menos na tabela `presenca`.

Comment: Definitivamente a primeira opção é a mais indicada.